# beforeFilter in AppController is not Calling when login action is call

Tags: cakephp

beforeFilter action is not calling from appController when i use UserController to login.

when I was developing it on the localhost it works fine. But in the Production server beforeFilter, beforeRender etc. actions are not calling, thats why i can not login into my app.

Any body have any solutions. How to overcome this bad situation   ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your production server's and local mahines date/time. If you can't login opnproduction system and there is no problem in local machine, it is very common that session is simply expired immediatly after login -> it ends befor it starts, cos of time on local system is way in the future compared to server's time...

Comment: suddenly I saw my server's support they don't support session still now. Is this a problem not to login to my app. If this is the problem, how can i login to my app without session ? I know about the cookie but  actually I don't know the steps to use only cookie for login process. Can you help me...?

Comment: This is the Support Link where they said about session ::::  http://support.wpengine.com/php-session-variables/